# Calling a function every 2 minutes

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I'm working on a plugin for a Minecraft server which automatically breaks melons for melon farms. It loops through all the blocks in all players' current chunks, and breaks the blocks that are melons. At first, I attempted to continuously call this function with a `while` loop in the `onEnable` method, however that caused the server to time/lag out. Without the `while` loop (only calling the function once from the `onEnable`), the plugin worked fine. Every time I reloaded the server, the function would run and all melons would be broken; so I decided to make a timer that would call the function every two minutes. For some reason, the server still times out, even with the timer, which I don't understand

Here's my code:

```
package me.spigot.itiurray.main;

import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.Chunk;
import org.bukkit.Material;
import org.bukkit.block.Block;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    private long goTime = 0;

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getLogger().info("MelonDrop has been enabled.");
        startBreakWithInterval();
    }

    private void breakMelons() {
        for (Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
            Chunk chunk = player.getLocation().getChunk();

            int x = chunk.getX() << 4;
            int z = chunk.getZ() << 4;

            for (int xx = x; xx < x + 16; xx++) {
                for (int zz = z; zz < z + 16; zz++) {
                    for (int yy = 0; yy < 256; yy++) {

                        Block block = chunk.getBlock(xx, yy, zz);

                        if (block.getType().equals(Material.MELON_BLOCK))
                            block.breakNaturally();

                        goTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 120000;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void startBreakWithInterval() {
        boolean running = true;

        while (running == true) {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() >= getGoTime())
                breakMelons();
        }
    }

    private long getGoTime() {
        return goTime;
    }
}
```

Edit: Here's what it currently looks like...

```
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        getLogger().info("MelonDrop has been enabled.");    

        scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> breakMelons(), 
2, 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    }
```

Comment: This isn't a comment to fix it, but I think you need to pull the goTime incrementation outside of your for loops, because it is incrementing up 12000*16*16*255 every time breakMelons() is called

Comment: `while(true) { doStuffMaybe(); }` you expect this loop to terminate before the end of the universe? When do you expect the game to get back to doing anything else?

Comment: The best way to do this in bukkit is using a Scheduler, such as using the BukkitRunnable class. Check my answer for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is stuck inside the `while(running == true)`

I suggest you to use a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html)

Answer (score 1):

For your time logic you should do the following

```
if(System.currentTimeMillis() - getGoTime() >= 120000)
{
    breakMelons();
}
```

Then inside your break melons function just call it at the very end of your method outside your for loop and do the following

```
goTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

The goTime variable should really just be the time at which you last completed breaking all the melons. Then when you check that time against the current system time you check if the time difference between the current time and the last time you executed the melon function is greater than 120000ms.

Answer (score 1):

A much clearer solution would look like this:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        breakMelons()
    }
}, 2, 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

This will be calling your method each 2 minutes. Also if you support java 8 then you could use the following syntax:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5);

scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(() -> breakMelons(), 2, 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

Comment: Tried this, however it seems to only run once.

Comment: That's probably because your scheduledExecutorService dies earlier, just before the second run. I have tried to change Minutes to MILLISECONDS and it works fine - calls the method several times. First of all, you shouldn't probably create scheduledExecutorService inside a method since it will be alive not that long time. Better to create it as a static field if you do not use any server side frameworks like Spring.

Comment: On the other hand, you could try a trick with adding while(true) right after scheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(..). This prevents your executor service from potential garbage collection after method execution has completed.

Comment: Check the edit, there's what it currently looks like. Thanks for this by the way.

Comment: Also, the one time that it does run, it doesn't end up breaking the melons. (Within the breakMelons() function I added a player.sendMessage in just under the for(Player player: Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()). The message sends, but it doesn't appear that the acutal breaking part is reached at all).

Comment: Yeah, that's because the first parameter means that the method will be executed in 2 minutes the first time. You could try changing it to be 0, so the first time it will fire will be immediately, and other times it will be delayed by 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

The correct solution for this is to use a BukkitRunnable. You can see more examples at [bukkit's documentation](https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Scheduler_Programming)

```
JavaPlugin plugin;    //Your plugin instance    
Long timeInSeconds = 10;
Long timeInTicks = 20 * timeInSeconds;
new BukkitRunnable() {

@Override
public void run() {
    //The code inside will be executed in {timeInTicks} ticks.
   //After that, it'll be re-executed every {timeInTicks} ticks;
  //Task can also cancel itself from running, if you want to.

   if (boolean) {
       this.cancel();
   }

}
}.runTaskTimer(plugin, timeInTicks, timeInTicks);   //Your plugin instance, 
                                                   //the time to wait until first execution,
                                                  //the time inbetween executions.
```

Answer (score -1):

Most other answers use BukkitRunnables and other native Java libraries. The best way to do this would be using a schedule task using a Runnable, not a BukkitRunnable.

```
Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(myPlugin, new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        breakMelons();
    }
}, 0, 2400);
```

The code below uses the recommended way of running a simple task repeatedly.

The reason you do not want to use BukkitRunnables the way that is recommended in another answer is because it creates a variable that is called and then left orphaned. This code uses an inline anonymous inner class in order to keep everything neat and tidy, while also giving you the same effect.

The only time you want to use a BukkitRunnable rather than just a normal Runnable, is when you have an intention of stopping the task in the future.

Comment: Attention! Using a Runnable and schedule it is virtually the same thing as a BukkitRunnable, but BukkitRunnable is actually the recommended way. Also, some Java mistakes in your answer: It does instantiate a BukkitRunnable, that will get garbage collected when it's done. Creating an anonymous inner class is the same process of instantiating a Runnable.

Comment: BukkitRunnable should only be used if you want to actually use the resulting task. Although it is not that much, BukkitRunnables have more memory overhead than a Runnable does. That is not a "Java mistake," it's a purposeful decision to properly optimize memory.