# How to execute a function every 10 seconds

Tags: java, plugins, sleep, minecraft, bukkit

I am making a plugin for my upcoming Minecraft server. I need a way to execute a function every 10 seconds.

I am fairly new to plugin development and Java. If anyone could help me I would appreciate it.

This is my code:

```java
public void endGame(){
    for (int y=0;y<256;y++){
        for (int x=0;x<384;x++){
            for (int z=0;z<384;z++) {
                Location loc = new Location(Bukkit.getServer().getWorld(player.getWorld().getName()), x, y, z);
                loc.getBlock().setType(Material.REDSTONE_BLOCK);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I have tried is:

```
public void endGame(){
    for (int y=0;y<256;y++){
        for (int x=0;x<384;x++){
            for (int z=0;z<384;z++) {
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(10000);
                    Location loc = new Location(Bukkit.getServer().getWorld(player.getWorld().getName()), x, y, z);
                    loc.getBlock().setType(Material.REDSTONE_BLOCK);
                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44593892/6395627

Comment: @Slaw Unfortunately none of your solutions would work in minecraft. Thread.sleep would freeze the game or desynchronize an other thread, Timer and ScheduledExecutorService is not guaranteed to execute when the game is in the correct state, although I think the bukkit way I used below is based on ScheduledExecutorService.

Comment: @tibetiroka I figured. One of the reasons I linked an answer I think should help. Deleted other comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use BukkitRunnable for task scheduling.

```
new BukkitRunnable().runTaskTimer(plugin,20*10,20*10);
```

BukkitRunnable is abstract, so you have to override the

```
@Override
public void run() {             
}
```

method. This method runs whenever the task is executed. The above `runTaskTimer()` method takes 3 parameters: a plugin instance, a long defining the delay before the first execution and an other long which is the time between executions. The time is measured in game ticks (1/20 second). You can read the [javadoc](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/scheduler/BukkitRunnable.html) and the [official tutorial](https://bukkit.gamepedia.com/Scheduler_Programming) for more info about scheduling.

If you interact with (modify) the bukkit environment in any way, it is strongly recommended to do so in the main thread only. Otherwise you can also use the `runTaskTimerAsynchronously` method.

**Why your code didn't work**

Your code was executed on the main thread. This thread handles basically every action related to the game, including block modifications, entity movements and player interactions. When you called Thread.sleep(), you froze the whole game. If you were to create a new thread and make that sleep for 10 seconds it would work, but you would be unable to modify the world, because your thread would not be in sync with the main thread.

Comment: `BukkitRunnable` can not be instantized ;-;

Comment: As I said, it is an abstract class. You have to override the run() method.

Comment: new BukkitRunnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
   
   }
  }.runTaskTimerAsynchronously(plugin, delay, cycle);

Answer (score 0):

I have a [gist](https://gist.github.com/OskarZyg/1d3373bd86ff9d34f11e505b8cd0c3aa) on how to do this. Create a class:

```
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public abstract class RepeatingTask implements Runnable {
    private int taskId;

    public RepeatingTask(JavaPlugin plugin, int initialDelay, int repeatDelay) {
        this.taskId = Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask(plugin, this, (long)initialDelay, (long)repeatDelay);
    }

    public void cancelLoop() {
        Bukkit.getScheduler().cancelTask(this.taskId);
    }
}
```

Unlike just creating a loop with `Bukkit.getScheduler().scheduleSyncRepeatingTask()`, you can actually cancel the loop with this class. Both the arguments are in ticks. (1 Second = 20 Ticks)

Usage of the class:

```
RepeatingTask repeatingTask = new RepeatingTask(this, 0, 20) {
  @Override
  public void run() {
      cancelLoop();
  }  
}
```